# Flutter apk running fine in release mode and debug mode but built apk not working?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have an app running fine in flutter run and flutter run --release.
I am using flutter [flutter_ssh](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_ssh) plugin(this plugin is not connecting)
I have already given the required permission internet permission in main manifest file
But built apk not working
this is my [repo](https://github.com/prinzpiuz/MSM_mobile)

Answer (score 1):

issue solved by building apk using 
`flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-shrink`
or
`flutter build apk --no-shrink`